# If links are prefetched, why does it take so long to open a page?

Tags: next.js

My understanding of NextJS is that it prefetches pages that are within the viewport, but in our case it still takes 3-4 seconds to load the subsequent page (even when deployed to production).

Is there anything we can do to speed this up? We're used to Gatsby where the load time is somewhere near zero.

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev-tools to see _why_ it's taking 3-4 seconds? Is it TTFB? Or something else? How is your server-side implemented?

Comment: "My understanding of NextJS is that it prefetches pages that are within the viewport" - don't speculate. Have you looked at your browser's dev-tools network tab to see if it's **actually** prefetching pages?